# I need to write a program that performs arithmetic operations using basic function with C

Tags: c, math

The program would take a total of three integers: two numbers for the operation and an additional number that indicates the type of the operation

The third number would be one of the following four:

1. addition,
2. subtraction,
3. multiplication,
4. division.

Here it would be assumed that division by zero would not happen.

How should I use the following function `'operation(int a, int b, int c)'` for the arithmetic operation? I'm a beginner in coding overall and I'm having a hard time figuring this question out.

Comment: Have you heard of `if`/`else`?

Comment: Are you using C, C++, or C# ?

Comment: yes i kinda tried using if/else for the third integer part.

Comment: I'm using C for this

Comment: Friendly tip: `enum`s are a nice way to turn a human-readable option into an `int`. Stef's second example would work great with an enum made for the various languages. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Performing one operation and returning the result

Here is how to perform an addition:

```c
int addition(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}
```

### Doing something different depending on a condition

Here is how to greet someone depending on a variable indicating their language:

```c
/*
** language:
**  0 - English;
**  1 - French;
**  2 - Spanish.
*/
void greetings(char const *name, int language)
{
    if (language == 0)
    {
        printf("Good morning, %s!\n", name);
    }
    else if (language == 1)
    {
        printf("Bonjour, %s !\n", name);
    }
    else if (language == 2)
    {
        printf("Buenos dias, %s !\n", name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry, %s. I have not learned Chinese yet.\n", name);
    }
}
```

### Combining the two things we've learned today

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I just kinda finished writing out the code and when I executed it, it worked! However, Im just curious that would it be write to use 'void' in front of the function and not double? I think im getting confused between these return-types.

Comment: `int` means the function returns an integer, `double` means the function returns a non-integer number, and `void` means the function doesn't return anything. With the two example functions I gave, you could write for instance `int x = addition(3, 4);` which would set `x` to `7`; but you are not allowed to write `int x = greetings("taechler", 3);` because `greetings("taechler", 3)` is not a value. The function `greetings` "does" something (printing out a greeting to screen), but it doesn't return a value.